# Making main window transparent

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, transparency, wxwidgets

What I want to do is force the main frame window background color to be completely transparent.

The only very first method I've found so far is the `SetTransparent(wxByte alpha)`function. However, this seems to be setting the transparency for the children controls as well - and I don't want that.

I've been trying multiple ways to achieve that, none worked though. Also, most questions regarding this seem to be outdated. Is there any working method (for Windows) which will allow me to set the full transparency for the main frame window?

Comment: It might help if you told us a bit more about what you've tried. For example, what (if any) use have you made of `SetLayeredWindowAttribute`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Honestly I've been tried everything that I found in the Google results. wxWidgets documentation is pretty huge so I need to read everything from the begging, carefully. However, I've never tried the `SetLayeredWindowAttribute` method, could you tell more about that?

Answer (score 0):

@Jerry Coffin pointed me in the right direction and I have made a *working* solution for this. However I still think that mixing both WinAPI and wxWidgets is not the best idea. But well, it works.

```
wxColour transparentColor = wxColour(wxTransparentColour);

SetBackgroundColour(transparentColor);
SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_CUSTOM);

SetWindowLong(GetHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(GetHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetHandle(), transparentColor.GetRGB(), 255, LWA_ALPHA);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetHandle(), transparentColor.GetRGB(), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Comment: Strange, this code doesn't seem to make much sense. You're setting alpha to be fully opaque and yet you somehow get a transparent window? Normally I'd expect `SetTransparent(0)`, which is equivalent to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(..., 0, LWA_ALPHA)` to do this...

Comment: @VZ. Yeah, that a bit strange but it works. SetTransparent(0) would simply make a whole application transparent (main windows + all of its childrens). I've spent 2 hours on it and this is the only working solution I found.